# BorderLayout not working JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

For some reason I can't get the `BorderLayout` to set the way it's supposed to. Just would like to know where I'm going wrong.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorFactory extends JFrame
{

    final int width = 500;
    final int height = 300;

    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JPanel radioButtonPanel;
    private JLabel msgChangeColor;

    public ColorFactory()
    {
        setTitle("Color Factory");
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        createTopPanel();
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        createBottomPanel();
        add(radioButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        msgChangeColor = new JLabel("Top buttons change the panel color and bottom radio buttons change the text color.");
        add(msgChangeColor, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }

    private void createTopPanel()
    {   
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton redButton = new JButton("Red");
        redButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
        redButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        redButton.setActionCommand("R");

        JButton orangeButton = new JButton("Orange");
        orangeButton.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        orangeButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        orangeButton.setActionCommand("O");

        JButton yellowButton = new JButton("Yellow");
        yellowButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        yellowButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        yellowButton.setActionCommand("Y");

        buttonPanel.add(redButton);
        buttonPanel.add(orangeButton);
        buttonPanel.add(yellowButton);

    }

    private void createBottomPanel()
    {
        radioButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JRadioButton greenRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Green");
        greenRadioButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        greenRadioButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        greenRadioButton.setActionCommand("G");

        JButton blueRadioButton = new JButton("Blue");
        blueRadioButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        blueRadioButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        blueRadioButton.setActionCommand("B");

        JButton cyanRadioButton = new JButton("Cyan");
        cyanRadioButton.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        cyanRadioButton.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());
        cyanRadioButton.setActionCommand("C");

        radioButtonPanel.add(greenRadioButton);
        radioButtonPanel.add(blueRadioButton);
        radioButtonPanel.add(cyanRadioButton);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String actionColor = e.getActionCommand();
            if(actionColor.equals("R"))
            {
                buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
                radioButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }

            if(actionColor.equals("O"))
            {
                buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                radioButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            }

            if(actionColor.equals("Y"))
            {
                buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                radioButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        }
    }
        private class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String actionTextColor = e.getActionCommand();
                if(actionTextColor.equals("G"))
                {
                    msgChangeColor.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                }

                if(actionTextColor.equals("B"))
                {
                    msgChangeColor.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }

                if(actionTextColor.equals("C"))
                {
                    msgChangeColor.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
                }
            }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ColorFactory run = new ColorFactory();
            run.setVisible(true);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are changing the layout manager for the frame when you create your top and bottom panels...

```
private void createTopPanel() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // <--- This is call setLayout on the frame
```

This is why it's dangerous to...

- Extend from something like `JFrame` directly...
- Dynamically build components

It's all to easy to lose context and start effecting components you didn't actually want to...

Comment: so I changed it to buttonPanel.setLayout(new lowLayout()); and it works. had to remove pack(); to space out the panels. thanks for the help

Comment: *"..and it works. had to remove pack().."*  'it works' and 'removed pack' in the *same* description.  How odd.  If something only works *without* pack, it is a sign the GUI is very broken..

Comment: @user3752231 The problems not with `pack`.  Try using an `EmptyBorder` to generate more space around the component

Answer (score 1):

Another problem (besides the one posted by MadProgrammer) is that you add your components to the JFrame itself.

You should add content to the content pane of the frame which you can get by calling [`JFrame.getContentPane()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane--).

Example:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
Container c = f.getContentPane();
c.add(new JButton("In Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
c.add(new JButton("At the Bottom"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
c.add(new JButton("At the Top"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
c.add(new JButton("On the Left"), BorderLayout.WEST);
c.add(new JButton("On the Right"), BorderLayout.EAST);
```

You can set/change the content panel by calling `JFrame.setContentPane()`. The default content panel already has `BorderLayout` so you don't even need to change it nor to set a new panel.

Comment: As of Java 5 (I think) `JFrame#add` automatically redirects to the content pane, so there's no "real" reason you need to use `getContentPane`, other than aesthetics...

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're right, I didn't realize it. And yes, related methods were overridden starting with 5.0 to forward to the content pane.